# Bending moment in composite beam with internal "active" stress

Tags: stress-strain, moment, structural-beam

I am looking at a problem of a bending composite beam with a symmetric cross -section, $A(s)$. Above the neutral axis $s$ is material $U$ and below the neutral axis is material $L$. $U$ has an internal active compressive stress $\sigma_U(s) \geq 0$ and $L$ has an internal active compressive stress $\sigma_L(s) \geq 0$. These stesses cause the beam to bend, not elongate or compress. I am having a little bit of difficulty determining the correct bending moment due to the active stress in this case. Allow me to walk you through the problem.

Since this is a composite material, $U$ feels the stress from $L$ and vice versa. In this case, believe that the stress at a given cross-section as

$\sigma_{active}(s,y) = \sigma_U(s,y) - \sigma_L(s,y)$.

I believe it is so for the following reason. Let $y$ be the direction normal to the neutral axis and $y > 0$ in $U$ and $y < 0$ for $L$. If $\sigma_U(s,y) \neq 0$ and $\sigma_L(s,y) = 0$, then the beam is concave up which here corresponds to positive curvature. Then, the strain $\epsilon(s,y) = - \kappa(s) y$ is negative in $U$ and positive in $L$. A similar argument can be made with a non-zero stress in $L$ and zeros stress in $U$ to see that the strain is positive in $U$ and negative in $L$.

Now, the moment is defined as

$M_{active}(s) = \int_{A(s)} y \, \sigma_{active}(s,y) dA(s)$.

Now the question is what should be the right form of $\sigma_{active}(s,y)$ so that I can compute the moment. There is a force density $f_U(s,y)$ in $U$ and $f_L(s,y)$ in $L$ that is responsible for the active stress generation. Since the strain is linear in a cross-section, then I can write

$\sigma_{active}(s,y) = [f_U(s,y_{max}) - f_L(s,y_{min})] \, y$,

where $y_{max} = -y_{min}$ since the cross-section is symmetric. Does this sound right? If this is the case, then the active moment is simply

$M_{active}(s) = [f_U(s) - f_L(s)]I(s)$

and the net moment (sum of active moment and passive moment that opposes the active deformation) is

$M(s) = M_{passive}(s) - M_{active}(s) = EI(s) \kappa(s) - [f_U(s) - f_L(s)]I(s)$.

I'd appreciate if someone can give me a sanity check here.